# VBA Show message if nothing selected Listbox Multiselect

Tags: excel, vba

Currently have a multi select listbox, on button press it shows options which im going to pass to SQL, how do I get it so a msg shows if none are selected

```
Dim i As Integer

With Worksheets("SQL Sheet").ListBoxes("31")


    For i = 1 To .ListCount
        If .Selected(i) Then
            result = result & "','" & .List(i)
        End If
    Next i

End With

result = result & "'"
result = Right(result, Len(result) - 2)
MsgBox result
```

Comment: You can check `if result <> "" then`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav there is no such method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim i As Integer

With Worksheets("SQL Sheet").ListBoxes("31")

    result = ""

    For i = 1 To .ListCount
        If .Selected(i) Then
            result = result & "','" & .List(i)
        End If
    Next i

End With

if result <> "" then
  result = result & "'"
  result = Right(result, Len(result) - 2)
  MsgBox result
else
  Msgbox "Nothing Selected."
End  if
```

Comment: Brill, that got it! Thanks!